# How to enable python built-in help and function completion?

Tags: python, emacs

I am using Emacs 24.3.1 on Windows to write Python code. I use built-in `python.el`. Both programs work fine.
Now I want to enable Python auto-completetion and the Python help.

I have read that eldoc supports reading Python documentation and that it is possible to enable auto-complete of Python functions. But it doesn't seem to work.

I added `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)` to my `.emacs` file.
After launching the Python interpreter I tried to use `help on symbol` (C-c C-f), I was prompted for "Describe symbol ...:" and I put `print` and pressed Enter - nothing happened.

The behavior of the complete function is similar: I wrote `import os` than `os.p` and used `complete symbol` (C-M-i) and got the output "no match".

Any suggestions how to resolve this?